# Spring @Transactional not proxying when referenced on xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on some legacy code that uses spring bean definitions on xml.
The module I am building uses annotations.

The problem is that sometimes I need to override a legacy bean definition so I need to put my beans on xml as well.

I have the following:

```
public class BeanIAmOverriding {
    private MyAnnotatedBean bean;
}

@Component
public class MyAnnotatedBean {
    private Repository repo;
}

@Repository
public class Repository {

    @Transational
    public Something find(...)
}
```

Xml file:

```
<bean id="bean" class="a.b.c.BeanIAmOverriding"/>
```

In this scenario, my repository does NOT get proxied with the transactional aspec.

I even tried just aliasing it but the same thing happens.
My current workaround is implementind BeanFactoryAware.

Do you have any better ideas?

EDIT:
Let me clarify.
I do know dependency injection, I just ommited some configuration I didn't think would be that relevant given the context, but here they are.

I would like to do something like:

```
<bean id="bean" class="a.b.c.BeanIAmOverriding">
     <constructor-arg index="0" ref="myAnnotatedBean"/>
 </bean>
```

That doesn't work. When I do that my Repository does not get proxied by the transactional aspect.

So I have this workaround:

```
public class BeanIAmOverriding implements BeanFactoryAware{
    //private MyAnnotatedBean bean;
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public void something(){
    beanFactory.getBean(MyAnnotatedBean.class).doSomething();
    }

     @Override
     public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you injecting `BeanIAmOverriding.bean`? ... as it looks like it will remain null.

Comment: @Augusto with the workaround: `public class BeanIAmOverriding implements BeanFactoryAware {  
    private MyAnnotatedBean bean;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, the problem is that you're not injecting the 'BeanIAmOverriding.bean', as spring doesn't know it has to inject it! Try the following (I'm not 100% sure if the following will work, as it's been a long time since I worked on a project that used a mix of 'legacy' xml and annotations).

```
public class BeanIAmOverriding {
    private MyAnnotatedBean bean;

    @Autowired
    public BeanIAmOverriding(MyAnnotatedBean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
}
```

The `@Autowired` annotation will tell spring how to instantiate the class. Spring will then take the instance of `MyAnnotatedBean` and inject it in the constructor.

I'm not sure how experienced you are with Spring, but I would recommend you to read a bit the section on [dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).